# Zip file created with ZipOutputStream does not open in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, zipoutputstream

I have a Zip file which has been created from a code using `ZipOutputStream` and I'm sending it across to a Ubuntu machine in my network.

But when I try to open it, it says that "Archive file is not accessible." although it opens perfectly in Windows.

Is this a Windows-only thing? Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: It says not >>accessible<< ?   Sounds like there is a problem with permissions and / or the way that you "sent it across the network".

Comment: I tried a small example. Seems to be working for me. Can you try with some simple files and may be share the code?